# Contour detection from area geometry coordinates txt

Tags: algorithm

I need to solve a contour detection problem. I define it as follows.

A contour detection is to recognize the outer rim of the given neighbor areas.

OK. So I have a txt file that defines the area geometry with their corner (boundary) points. Points have coordinates. With this, the need is to find the contour.

Please check the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftlle.png) to understand better.

I would like to use an existing algorithm if there is one already. If there is no algorithm that can solve this then I would like to hear algorithmic ideas about the steps that will lead to the solution.

I appreciate any help here..

Thanks in advance. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If the areas are all touching (i.e. no enclosed blank spaces)

- Add all edges to some set
- Search for edges which are *overlapping*, and partition them to get the two parts which do *not* overlap; remove the parts which are. (e.g. 7-8 of A2 and 10-9 of A3 ==> 7-10 + 8-9, removing 8-10 from both edges)
- In the remaining set, remove the edges which are still touching (e.g. 8-9 of A3 and A4). This combined with the previous step will remove all internal edges.
- You have the set of outer rim edges.

Comment: edges are defined by corner nodes(x,y) i.e coordinates -  if two edges touching one may be smaller or bigger than the other, how shall the algorithm know which edge to remove

Comment: @sinchocode do some simple algebra to find the _common_ segment between the two lines, and always remove that because that's not gonna be part of the rim

Comment: OK @willy thank you very much, seems like a viable solution. I will try to code it.

Comment: @sinchocode if you want I can do a bit on the intersection